# Policy for stolen edit requests

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

If an edit request is made by a user with less than 2000 rep, and that edit request is then denied by a reviewer, and reviewer then makes the edits that were suggested so that he/she gets credit in the history, how should we handle this?

Do we have a policy to deal with or prevent this? Or is edit credit a minor enough thing that we shouldn't bother with this issue?

Comment: A link to the post and/or suggested edit might be helpful here.

Comment: I don't want to call anyone out, and would prefer a general discussion of the issue rather than highlighting one instance.

Comment: I understand that. The reason I asked is because sometimes there is something else going on that we can't possibly know without having the facts.

Comment: In my case, the other user used my exact edits and added his own to it. I've seen this done plenty of times, and it's shown as I edited and then the other user edited in the history. In this case, my edits were deleted from the history by the other user claiming them as his own.

Comment: Users who are able to vote on edit suggestions don't gain rep from making edits

Comment: @SamIam I know, which just makes it seem even more petty.

Comment: Just a hopefully helpful note; When questioning something someone's done, try not to assume the worst right out of the gate. Keep an open mind and try to see if you can understand what's being explained. Using words like 'petty' to refer to someone's actions can unnecessarily color what should otherwise be an objective conversation.

Comment: @Brian: your edits were never **added** to the history. You made a edit **suggestion** and not until it has been accepted, would it be in the history, at all. Your edit was never *removed*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Exactly. So the reviewer is simply writing him/her-self into the history instead of the actual editor. Hence my question: should we prevent that, or does it matter?

Comment: @Brian It doesn't matter

Comment: @Brian: No, the editor did the *work that should have been done*. I'm not sure what value you attach to someone being listed in the edit history here, but there is no reputation or badge or status attached to that. Bottom line is that if you put more effort into your edits, this wouldn't be needed.

Comment: @Brian No, we certainly should not prevent this. The point of being able to uncheck the "helpful" box is to discourage / not credit suggested edits that fail to address **all** the needed corrections in a post.

Comment: @SamIam There! It could use some further explanation, but finally someone actually answered the question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Please see the edits I made to the question to prevent it from being further derailed. Your answer and most of your comments do not currently pertain to the question, and have completely derailed what should have been a constructive discussion.

Comment: @Brian: But your interpretation of the process is *still wrong*. There is specific functionality to *improve* a suggested edit, that includes marking the edit as *not helpful*. That is **not** stealing, that is specific behaviour the system allows and encourages.

Comment: @Brian: your casting of this process as 'petty' and 'stealing' is not helping this discussion.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You *still* aren't reading what I wrote. In the question, the reviewer rejects the edits, then posts the exact same edits, adding nothing. Your putting words in my mouth is certainly not helping the discussion either, as I never referred to the process as either of those things, but rather the actions of a hypothetical reviewer.

Comment: @Brian The reviewer can do that as even though their edits are **minor** since they are going to be directly posted they are not subject to the  _too minor edit rule_ as they will not be placed in the review queue. Please see my answer

Comment: @secretformula I actually did see your answer, I was the one upvote so far. You stayed on topic and you were thorough, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Brian: I am not going to go back and forth with you here. The suggested edit system *will copy your edit* and let the editor improve this. You are looking at this feature from the wrong end of the spectrum.

Comment: I don't get what the problem is. The site is collaboratively edited. **So what if you don't get the credit? The post still got improved and everyone still benefits.** When I read the title, I thought you were going to describe the case where a suggested edit got erroneously rejected, then someone with full editing privileges went back in and submitted the edit. Naturally, the suggester wouldn't get the credit in this case, but that rather misses the point. Is that really a "stolen edit"? Is clicking the "improve" button really "stealing"? And is there really a harm?

Comment: @CodyGray "I thought you were going to describe the case where a suggested edit got erroneously rejected, then someone with full editing privileges went back in and submitted the edit." That is what I'm saying, but with the person who rejected it being the same one who went back and made the same edit afterward. I've only suggested it being intentional, but the rejection being unintentional is certainly up for discussion too.

Comment: Just to be sure: you do know that at least 3 people need to look at your suggested edit during the review process? I'd say that just removing "hello" and "thanks" is not worth their time, and also is not worth even as little as 2 reputation. Your suggestion being rejected should teach you something. To me, your comments here indicate you're not open to any feedback. Also, *"the person who rejected it being the same one who went back and made the same edit"* is false; it's all part of the same process. Please read Martijn's answer again.

Comment: @Arjan Martijn's answer does not address the question, but rather talks about a specific instance. This question is not about that instance.

Comment: They didn't actually, they clicked the "improve" button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe what everyone is trying to say is that most likely if there is a case where an edit was rejected and then subsequently the same edits were made by a reviewer there is no malice going on.

1. As a reviewer I honestly have no motivation in doing my 20 reviews each day other than the 400+ reviews I still need to get the gold badge, and the feeling/hope that I'm making Stack Overflow a better place. A reviewer gets **NO +2** for any edits they make. Thus it is not in their interest to steal any edits.
2. As has been mentioned, suggested edits need to be substantial as not to take up time from reviewers for minor edits. In a lot of cases what feels like a stolen edit, is simply a reviewer acknowledging the edit should be made, but doesn't feel it was worthy of being a suggested edit (taking up a place in the finite review queue).

In short, I think I can speak for Stack Overflow when I say we love you and thank you for your suggested edits! Just make sure that when you suggest an edit it is on something **major** and not minor, eventually you will make it to be a 2k+ user and then you can fix those damned typos :)

Answer (score 28):

[This suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5072777) was rejected as not substantive enough. You missed issues with the post that should have been edited beyond the simple removing of *Hi* and *thanks*.

The last reviewer also chose the 'improve' option, and unchecked the 'helpful' box when they did so. They then [*fixed the other issues* with the post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4213197/revisions).

Try and make your edit *count*, and not just make a minor edit removing the low-hanging fruit.

Note that when a reviewer uses the *improve* option, they don't get extra credit over the review itself (other than another edit count towards edit-related badges). A reviewer doesn't get reputation for the edit. The editor instead is opting for the warm glow of having *improved the site*.

The site specifically *allows* for a suggested edit to be improved, *including* marking the original suggested edit as *not helpful*. This is **not stealing**. However, if you see a suggested edit that *was substantial* and was subsequently rejected through an improve action with the 'helpful' checkbox unmarked *with little to no actual improvement* beyond the edit, you can flag that edit for moderator attention. *99 out of 100 times* however, such cases are honest mistakes, as the *editor doesn't gain anything substantive from this behaviour*.

In fact, due to the speed that the suggested edits queue on Stack Overflow is processed, most editors *don't bother* with the 'improve' option as the edit will already have been rejected or accepted by the time they are done with editing. There is a high chance their work is for naught, so most reviewers don't bother.

Comment: In similar situations that I've seen in the past, the reviewer adds their own additions to the suggested edit. In this case, he rejected my edits and used them himself, and added more in. I feel that my edits did make a difference, and the reviewer must have too, or he wouldn't have used them himself.

Comment: Also, as I pointed out in the comments above, I stated this as a general discussion rather than highlighting one instance so that we can have a productive discussion and not end up with answers like "your edits weren't good enough, his made it better, deal with it".

Comment: Because a suggested edit consumes community time for the approval process, suggested edits have a higher bar to meet than regular edits.  The person who rejects your suggestion, and then improves the rest of the post (incorporating your edit), is saying "your edit wasn't substantial enough to warrant the time spent reviewing it."

Comment: @Brian this is one of those "something else going on that we can't possibly know without having the facts" which I was talking about.

Comment: @Brian: You **removed** text. That is hardly 'stealing' your work. Noone took your text as their own.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't have mentioned that I experienced this at all, because it causes people to obsess on a single instance and quickly become condescending. I stated this question to not be about a specific instance, and with the assumption that the hypothetical reviewer did not add any significant edits. This answer answers the question "Why was my edit rejected?", but that is NOT what I'm asking.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Again, I'm not referring to that specific instance. Please consider the question at hand.

Comment: @Brian: There are many different reasons edits can be rejected, the most common one being that the edit is too minor. However, your question started with a premise that your edit was *stolen*. It is that erroneous premise that derailed your intentions here.

Comment: @Brian: If you have a *much better* example of a 'stolen' edit, I'd love to see that. Until such time, I'm sticking with: You misunderstood what happened here, your edit was nowhere near substantive enough and you failed to meet the minimum standards of a suggested edit. The editor went beyond the call of duty to reject the edit, and instead did all the work that was required instead.

Comment: @Brian: note that that editor did not gain any reputation from that edit. They improved the site instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Please read my other comments. The question I have posed assumes that the reviewer's own contributions are negligible.

Comment: @Brian: so? The reviewer has 2k+ reputation, they can make any edit directly and are not bound by the minimal edit requirements of a suggested edit, *because they are not subjecting that edit to review*.